# How to get an organization's logo url using LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

Using LinkedIn's organization API https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations/xxxx, we can only get the `logoV2` object which contains URNs of the logo. I need the url of the logo so that I can show it in my web app. Any help is appreciated.